# struct Test: Identifiable vs class Test: Identifiable

Tags: swift

```
struct Test: Identifiable {}
```

causes the error: "Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'Identifiable'".
It wants "id" property.

```
class Test: Identifiable {}
```

compiles without any problems.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SE-0261 Identifiable Protocol](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0261-identifiable.md) (emphasis mine):

> In order to make it as convenient as possible to conform to Identifiable, **a default id is provided for all class instances:**
>
> ```
> extension Identifiable where Self: AnyObject {
>     var id: ObjectIdentifier {
>         return ObjectIdentifier(self)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Then, a class whose instances are identified by their object identities need not explicitly provide an id:
>
> ```
> final class Contact: Identifiable {
>     var name: String
>
>     init(name: String) {
>         self.name = name
>     }
> }
> ```